# How to create array of classes containing a constructor with reference argument?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have the piece of code hereunder which gives me the following errors:

```
test.cpp:15:38: error: could not convert ‘std::ref<boost::asio::io_context>(((container*)this)->container::ioCtxt)’ from ‘std::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_context>’ to ‘A’
   15 |     std::array<A,2> bObjs = {std::ref(this->ioCtxt), nullptr};
      |                              ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      std::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_context>
test.cpp:15:61: error: could not convert ‘nullptr’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘A’
   15 |     std::array<A,2> bObjs = {std::ref(this->ioCtxt), nullptr};
      |                                                             ^
      |                                                             |
      |
```

This is the minimal piece of code which creates the error in question. This minimal piece of code is a simplistic representation of a more complex situation.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>


struct A
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock;
    A(boost::asio::io_context& ioCtxtFromContainer): sock(ioCtxtFromContainer){}
};

struct container
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioCtxt;

    std::array<A,2> bObjs = {std::ref(this->ioCtxt), nullptr};
};

int main(void)
{
    container containerObj;

    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct way of passing a reference to A's constructor? Using vectors or an other form of dynamic memory allocation is not allowed/possible here.

Comment: I don't think you can with arrays. You can use vector and emplace instead, or individual variable members.

Comment: @MarcStevens updated my post. Using vectors or any other type of dynamic memory allocation is not allowed here.

Comment: did you try without `std::ref`?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik nullptr would still be the problem.

Comment: @alagner read my answer then

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I've just done it :) I guess the bottom line is what OP really wants to achieve. As memory allocation is not possible  optionals seemed the most sane default to me.

Comment: What is the purpose of `std::ref` here to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Conmpiler can't do implicit conversion via initializer list:

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>

struct from{};

struct a
{
    a(from&){}
};

int main()
{
    from arg{};
    // std::array<a, 1> ar{std::ref(arg)}; // can't deduce from initializer list
    std::array<a, 1> ar{ arg }; // alright
    std::array<a, 1> ar2{ a(arg) }; // also alright
}
```

2. How do you expect to initialize from a Pointer something, that takes a reference?

```
A(boost::asio::io_context& ioCtxtFromContainer):
```

You store an array of **objects**, not an array of pointers. So, either provide a constructor for `A` which takes a pointer (which is not what you pbviously want), or have an array of pointers: `std::array<A*, 2>` (using smart pointers preferrably).
Or you can use `std::optional`, like alanger has suggested.

---

You can wrapp your initializer list for your array with a variadic template:

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::array<a, sizeof...(Args)> init_array(Args &&... args)
{
    return {a(std::forward<Args>(args))...};
}
    
from arg{};
auto ar3 = init_array(arg, std::ref(arg)); // works
```

Comment: >> How do you expect to initialize from a Pointer something, that takes a reference?<<

You can use std::ref to pass a reference, like so: https://www.godbolt.org/z/anTEe4o4o
So I'd expect this to work here as well. No idea what you re speaking about...

Comment: I'm speaking about the second element of your `std::array<A, 2>` (which is an array of **objects**), that you are trying to initialize via `nullptr`.

Comment: Also, `bObjs = { a, b } ;` is an initialization from `initializer list`.  It expects an object of class `A` or something, that can be used for to construct an object of `A` via **no more than one** user-defined conversion. `A <- asio::io_context& ` is one implicit "conversion". `A <- asio::io_context& <- std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context&>` - two conversions. Initializer list can't deduce how `A` can be constructed from something other than a reference. And `std::reference_wrapper` is not a reference, it is a wrapper with a conversion operator

Comment: btw, read carefully the error in your godbolt link. It doesn't compile for another reason than you think

Comment: OK, so I carefully re-read your answer and comments. Regarding this: >>std::array<a, 1> ar{ arg };<< Is there a way to rewrite this part somehow so it scales better? Because if I were to have an array of eg 50 structs, I would not want to manually write '{arg, arg,...};' 50 times. I will accept your answer after that. Thanks

Comment: @ostrich525 well it seems you have no problem with writing `std::ref(this->ioCtxt)` 50 times. As I've already mentioned, just don't use `std::ref` for initializer list: `{ this->ioCtxt, this->ioCtx, ... }` works fine. Is there any *specific* reason why you need it to be wrapped?

Comment: I figured out I don't need to use std::ref. I am still learning. But still, I would not want to write this->ioCtxt 50 times. if the length of the array is a #defined variable somewhere this solution will inevitably lead to a compile error as it is not scalable. I *guess* a macro could somehow do the trick here

Comment: @ostrich525 I've updated my answer with a variadic function to accept all kinds of stuff to initialize `A` from, even wrapped references.

Comment: @ostrich525 ` I would not want to write this->ioCtxt 50 times.` - this is not what your question is about. I suggest you ask a new one specifically on that topic.

Comment: Needless to say this is quite wild. Deserves to be accepted, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Store array of optionals if you need explicitly empty fields.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <array>


auto main() -> int
{
    std::array<std::optional<double>, 3> x {3.2, std::nullopt, 5.0};
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
or pre-C++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>


struct A
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock;
    A(boost::asio::io_context& ioCtxtFromContainer): sock(ioCtxtFromContainer){}
};

struct container
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioCtxt;

    std::array<boost::optional<A>,2> bObjs = {
        A{this->ioCtxt}, boost::none};
};

auto main() -> int
{
    container containerObj;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f9fhr5dnK

Comment: care to elaborate why you choose std::optional? I tried reading about it online, but it is not quite clear to me why it is needed here

Comment: @ostrich525 from your code he just assumed that you want to have some elements "uninitialized" in your array. Hence, `std::optional` is the simplest and overhead-free way to do so.

Comment: @ostrich525 I was not entirely sure what you wanted aside from just putting the object into the array but this `nullptr` (see your original post) suggsted that also some sort of "empty" marker is needed, as dynamic allocation (to resize the array) is not available. Optional is just the standard, popular and lightweight way to so.